# Set up config for prettier.js JetBrains

Tags: webstorm, jetbrains-ide, prettier

I use WebStorm latest version and I don't like to use double quotes:D

**The question** is how do I set up my own config for the `prettier.js` embedded
 in the JetBrains product? (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd>)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

WebStorm doesn't embed any prettier configs. You have to create your own [prettier configuration file](https://prettier.io/docs/en/configuration.html) in your project folder (or add `"prettier"` key to your `package.json`) and add the desired rules there, like

```
{
  "singleQuote": true
}
```

Comment: Спасибо за помощь, Елена!